# To occur - Complement or modifier

Tags: grammar

```
"It is also common for this construction **to occur** without inversion".
```

In this sentence, to occur that acts  as a Complement or Modifier?
To me, it appear as a complement to this sentence.

Comment: @ Araucaria - Not here any more , OK, but I asked how did it function?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> *It is also common* [*for this construction to occur without inversion*].

You are right: it's a complement.

The bracketed infinitival clause is complement of the adjective "common", the item that licenses it.

Note that the sequence "to occur" is not a constituent here, not a syntactic unit, but part of the predicate verb phrase "to occur without inversion" in which "to" is marker and "occur" is head.